# Why are my em values scaled differently between mobile and desktop views?

Tags: html, css, width, font-size

I'm having trouble with my understanding of how em should work in CSS. I'm trying to get an element (div in this case) to scale the same way the font does. I've narrowed my problem statement down as small as I can.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      body { font-size: 100%; }
      .EventReg {
        border:solid #000000 .063em;
        background-color:#000000;
        padding:.625em;
        width:13.65em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="font-size:2em;">Event Registration</div>
    <div class="EventReg"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This seems to scale correctly in IE, FF, and Chrome, when I change **body { font-size: 100%; }** to any other percent.

What I'm expecting is what I see in a computer browser the div and the text are the exact same length. However, when I check this with my android smart phone the text is quite a bit wider than the div.

I would expect the div under the text to be the same width as the text even though it's scaled.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or where my assumption is wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288813/responsive-css-ems-wont-resize-lower-than-0-5em/16289640#16289640) , I answered it a couple of days ago, and it's exactly what you want to know. In short: if you don't specify a pixel font-size first, the results of what 'em' stands for are not easy to predict.

Comment: I tried the following with no luck: **html { font-size: 16pt; },  html { font-size: 16px; }, body { font-size: 16pt; }, body { font-size: 16px; }**. This scales correctly on the computer browsers but not the phone.

Comment: That sucks... In that case I'm really interested in the solution to this problem...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by making the text an image. This was not an ideal solution for me, but it forces the text to be the same on all devices and browsers.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked, which is "why is this happening", not "how do I work around this?"

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with `-webkit-text-size-adjust` property. Try adding the following style to your css.

```
* {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
}
```

On some mobile phones, the browser adjusts the font size to make websites more readable. Setting that property to 100% (or possible `none`) should prevent that from happening.

Comment: I've tried both **-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%** and **-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;** but doesn't change the outcome. thanks.

Comment: In that case, I think Jukka's answer might be more helpful. You're probably seeing different results between desktop browsers and mobile because of different default fonts. If you set the font explicitly to something common like Arial, you might have better results, but even then there's no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to expect that the text and the empty `div` element are of the same width. The width of the text depends on the font, and possibly to some extent also on the font rendering features (such as kerning). The width of the empty `div` element is explicitly set using the `em` unit. [The `em` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#em-width) is the size of the font, i.e. the height of the font; it has no defined relationship to the width or height of letters.

To make the width of an element depend on the width of some text in another element you need things like table formatting, or other layout tools. In this case, if you just want a solid rectangle under the text, you can set e.g. `display: inline-block` and a suitable `border-bottom` on the element containing the text.